# SELECT x FROM table WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I've problem to create query for my situation:

I've table user:

```
ID   NAME   CREDITS

1   "AAA"   10000

2   "BBB"   20000

3   "CCC"   30000
```

and table store:

```
ID    ITEM_ID   ACTIVE

2    "table"    true

2    "chair"    false

1    "apple"    true
```

I want to select all NAMEs where ACTIVE for ID equals true, so for my situation output should be:

```
"AAA"
"BBB"
```

I did:

```
SELECT NAME FROM user WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM store WHERE ACTIVE=true);
```

but the first WHERE is wrong... i think. Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.NAME
FROM store
JOIN user ON store.ID = user.ID
WHERE ACTIVE = true
```

I will add that your question suggests that somehow the user ID has the same meaning as the store ID, which seems highly unlikely. More likely you shouldn't be comparing these ID columns.

Even more likely, you shouldn't be trying to join these two tables at all.

Comment: this query should be prefered over a subquery, in my opinion. +1

Comment: I think the `DISTINCT user.NAME` is over-kill?

Comment: @user2310289 it's in case `store.ID` is not unique. You're right - *hopefully* overkill, but with a schema as whacky as this, you knows!?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT NAME FROM user WHERE ID in (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM store WHERE ACTIVE=true);
```

Also, as mentioned by @Bohemian usually the `ID` field in a table refers to the unique identifier for that record in that table.  So the `User.ID` have no relevance to the `Store.ID`